# Can I run django server ingnore part of the project in Django?

Tags: python, django

Can I run django server ingnore part of the project in Django?

I have a Django project with several apps, and one of the apps is need to import openstacksdk(because it relay on many linux libs, in Mac env is very troublesome ), so I must work in the Linux operate system. but now I have done that app which must import openstacksdk.

Now I cloned the project from Linux to my mac, there will report error which related to openstacksdk.

This is the directory of my project:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So, is there a way only to debug the apps that do not contain the openstacksdk-related app?

Comment: You can use Vagrant or some other virtual machine to run Linux on your Mac. I am working on a Django project in Windows and another developer is using Linux and another is using Mac and we can all run the same code because we have identical environments installed inside Vagrant. Takes a bit of work to set up initially, but it should solve the problem.

Comment: @manassehkatz Thanks for your good recommend, I will check this.

Comment: To your question: you can create a new settings file without that app and use it as described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

Comment: You can use Docker https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Bump vagrant advice. Different codebases or settings files for each developer is almost guaranteed to lead to weird, hard to debug problems down the road. We took the time to set up vagrant and all of our lives are easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or some other virtual machine to run Linux on your Mac. I am working on a Django project in Windows and another developer is using Linux and another is using Mac and we can all run the same code because we have identical environments installed inside Vagrant. Takes a bit of work to set up initially, but it should solve the problem. Make sure to install an OS in Vagrant that is close to (identical isn't always possible, unfortunately) the production server OS.